# Async Task vs EF Async

Tags: entity-framework, async-await

**Estimados, necesito saber que diferencia existe entre estos dos metodos de recuperar informacion usando metodos asincronicos:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> RecuperarCotizacion(int _codigo)
    {
        JsonResult result = null;

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var db = new DAL("SYS"))
                {
                    var coti = db.PR_COTIMONE.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CODIGO == _codigo);
                    if(coti==null)
                        throw new Exception("Moneda no existe");

                    result = new JsonResult()
                    {
                        Data = new { status = true, codigo = _codigo, cotizacion = coti.COTIZACION },
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                        MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
                    };
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new { status = false, mensajeError = ex.Message },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
            };
        }

        return result;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> RecuperarCotizacion(int _codigo)
    {
        JsonResult result = null;

        try
        {   
            using (var db = new DAL("SYS"))
            {
                var coti =await db.PR_COTIMONE.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CODIGO == _codigo);
                if(coti==null)
                    throw new Exception("Moneda no existe");

                result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = new { status = true, codigo = _codigo, cotizacion = coti.COTIZACION },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                    MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
                };
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new { status = false, mensajeError = ex.Message },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
            };
        }

        return result;
    }
```

El primer codigo entiendo que genera un subproceso y accede a la BD desde el mismo, entonces no estaria usando el hilo principal de la BD, es correcto?

El segundo utiliza el metodo de EF asincronico, entiendo que accede desde un subproceso a la BD, es correcto?

Cual es mas eficiente?
Ambos realizan lo mismo?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es prácticamente lo mismo.

`Task.Run` crea una `Task<>` con un `Action<>` como argumento y lo ejecuta instantáneamente.
Sería equivalente a

```
Task t = new Task(() => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running as parallel");
});
t.Start(); // Esto es la deferred ejecution
```

El código dentro de una `Task` lo ejecuta un *thread* distinto.

Cuando hacemos un `await` sobre una `Task`, estamos ejecutando la `Action<>` propia de la `Task` en otro hilo y, además, estamos marcando un punto de retorno al *thread* que invocó la `Task`, al que llamaremos *main thread*.
El *main thread* puede seguir ejecutando otras tareas. Como se suele decir, "se libera". Pero una vez la `Task` se resuelve, vuelve al punto donde la invocó (ese es el *yielding*).

Tus dos métodos van a funcionar del mismo modo, ambos delegan a otro *thread* el acceso a la base de datos y esperan a esa resolución.

Por lo general, siempre que puedas evitar crear las `Task` por tu cuenta, evítalo. En tus dos ejemplos, la segunda opción sería la más correcta.

Sólo hay diferencias entre los dos métodos del ejemplo, ambas igual de sutiles que importantes.

- ***Memory sharing***
  En ambos métodos, la variable `result` se declara y después se inicializa. La diferencia es quién inicializa la variable. En el primer caso, es el *thread* paralelo que la inicializa. En el segundo, es el mismo *main thread* quien lo hace.
  Es muy sutil, pero en el segundo caso el *main thread* espera a la resolución del `FirstOrDefaultAsync` y asigna ese resultado a la variable `result`. Nadie más que el *main thread* necesita conocer la existencia de esa variable.
  En el primer método, es el mismo *thread* invocado quien asigna a esa variable, y eso puede dar problemas de concurrencia.
  Algo muy importante a recordar

  > Las variables siempre deben estar lo más contextualizadas posibles. Esto aplica a clases, métodos y, sobretodo *threads*.

Si surge alguna duda con este tema, coméntamelo y lo puedo ampliar un poco más.

- ***Performance***
  Este punto no es tan importante como el anterior, pero merece ser mencionado.
  Una de las razones por las que hay que usar los métodos *...Async* de las APIs (sobretodo las oficiales, como *Entity Framework*) es que en la mayoría de casos, estas APIs usan por dentro mejoras implementaciones sobre las `Task<>` y los `ValueTask<>`.
  A grandes rasgos, sólo deberíamos usar los métodos no asíncronos cuando no queremos/necesitamos asincronicidad.

Por último, cabe mencionar que hay situaciones donde no tenemos más remedio que definir nosotros las `Task` o, en algunos casos, por alguna razón nos beneficia.
También se da el caso de que querramos que dos o más *threads* compartan memoria, pero son casos justificados (y no accidentales, como en el ejemplo de arriba).

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias VRoxa, impecable aporte!, el codigo que puse fue algo rapido que hice, si es verdad el result tenia que quedar fuera del Task.Run. Pero con el tema del thread, del lado de C# lo tengo claro, mi duda era que hace SQL Server, si interpreta esa ejecucion en hilo secundario o lo ejecuta dentro del principal (en cada caso). Al menos FirstOrDefaultAsync  estoy casi seguro que hace que SQL lo ejecute en un hilo secundario, pero Task.Run estoy logrando lo mismo? Que opinas?

Comment: Toda `Task` se va a ejecutar en un *thread* paralelo (a menos que le hagas el *attach* al tuyo explícitamente). La duda que tienes es algo general para las `Task` ya sea aplicado a bases de datos, al *file system*, a llamadas HTTP, ... Cada librería y cada *framework* va a tratar las `Task` de igual manera porque es parte de C# (C#5.0 en caso de `async/await`). Así que las explicaciones que di se aplican a cualquier método que devuelva `Task`.

Comment: lo planteo de otra forma, mi duda es: que hace SQL Server cuando se usa Task.Run y dentro de este task se usa EF para hacer llamadas sincronicas (FirstOrDefult en vez de FirstOrDefaultAsync ) --> que hace sql lo ejecuta en un hilo secundario tambien?

Comment: Como he puesto en la respuesta. No hay diferencia en este sentido, ambas tareas se ejecutarán en segundo plano, en otro hilo.

Comment: del lado de .net si eso esta claro, pero SQL Server tambien lo va a hacer en segundo plano?

Comment: SQL Server como todos los *providers* de bases de datos tiene mil mecanismos para distribuir y ejecutar una enorme cantidad de operaciones simultáneamente. Así que no te preocupes por eso. Del lado de SQL Server no afecta cómo hagas la llamada a la base datos, ni siquiera si es asíncrona o no, la base de datos se va a comportar exactamente igual. La única diferencia reside en tu aplicación.

Comment: VRoxa, otra consulta. en la respuesta vi que decias que result en el primer metodo se asigna en el thread paralelo y en el segundo el thread principal, pero esto no es asi. en ambos se define antes del bloque Task.Run por tanto se definen en el principal. Al hacer esto porque decis que trae problema si se reasigna el valor de result dentro de Task y luego se hace el return fuera de Task, que problema trae?

Comment: Lo importante es quién le asigna el valor real que va a tener la variable. Tener variables las cuales son accesibles a varios *threads* es algo a evitar, ya que puede dar escenarios de [*race conditions*](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/race-conditions-in-threading-C-Sharp/) y [*deadlocks*](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/deadlock-in-threading-in-C-Sharp/). En tu escenario sólo debes preocuparte de los *race conditions*.